# Web service to get weather

Tags: c#, web-services, weather-api

I need a SOAP web service to provide me the current weather for the given city. I have checked NOAA, but seems it doesn't work. At least I have tried it with wcftestclient. 
Who have done something similar please suggest.

Comment: Did you follow this article? http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030205-1.aspx  Usually the 4Guys team is pretty good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find something using SOAP. So I stoped on google weather api. It works good for me.

Answer (score 1):

From a search of [xmethods.net](http://xmethods.net/ve2/index.po), I found the a [web service](http://wiki.cdyne.com/wiki/index.php?title=CDYNE_Weather) offered by CDYNE.  It is a free version to advertise their commercial service.

[Weather Underground](http://www.wunderground.com/) has an [API](http://wiki.wunderground.com/index.php/API_-_XML) to access their data using XML.  I know that you specified a SOAP web service, but I thought I would provide this information if you were interested.